# Syntax problem passing variable document.title in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using a web analytics package named Statcounter on my site.
They offer the ability send custom tags and gave me the following example line of code to add to each of my pages.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _statcounter = _statcounter || [];
_statcounter.push({"tags": {"userID": "john", "userType": "senior",    
"category": "media"}});
</script>
```

Their example worked successfully. However, for my application, I want to only send one custom tag, which is the title of the web page.
So I modified their example to the following line of code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _statcounter = _statcounter || [];
_statcounter.push({"tags": {"page title": document.title}});
</script>
```

This did not work. I'm wondering if there is an error in the syntax I'm using.
I did confirm that the Javascript variable document.title is correctly populated with the actual title of the web page.
Thank you

Comment: Will it works if you change `"page title"` to `"pageTitle"`?

Comment: `document.title` is OK. Maybe they don't accept white spaces in tag names. Did you try `pageTitle` as tag name instead?